# Ampersand in meta description tag

Tags: html

Might be a silly question, but i am asking because my site is not published/indexed so i cannot view the meta description. In sublime when i write a regular ampersand like "&" it is for some reason highlighted. I was wondering does & work the same in the meta description as it does in the regular html body?

For example:

```
<meta name="description" content="George &amp; Bill />
```

Would this be displayed properly or can you not use & in meta tags?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585754/does-need-to-be-amp-in-the-meta-description

Comment: Thank you, did not see that thread as a suggestion prior to submitting my question.